# Iterate over Mat returned by calcHist

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to learn [equalization of histograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization), of course I know there is [histogram equalization in OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html). I am [iterating over the `Mat` object](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-iterator-safe-method) returned by [`calcHist`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=pixel%20operators#calchist) and I don't know if this is the right way... or there are other ways. First of all, does [`calcHist`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=pixel%20operators#calchist) return a Mat of floats or doubles or ints? I can't seem to find this in the docs.

```
int histSize = 256;
float range[] = {0, 256} ;
const float* histRange = { range };

Mat histogram;
calcHist(&image, 1, 0, Mat(), histogram, 1, &histSize, &histRange);

Mat accumulatedHistogram = histogram.clone();   
MatIterator_<float> accHistIt, accHistEnd;  
accHistIt=accumulatedHistogram.begin<float>();
accHistEnd=accumulatedHistogram.end<float>();

bool firstLoop = true;

for(; accHistIt != accHistEnd; accHistIt++) {
    if(firstLoop) {                     
        firstLoop = false;
    } else {
        *accHistIt += *(accHistIt-1);
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: (accHistIt-1) will most certainly lead to a buffer underrun in the 1st iteration.   what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am trying to calculate this: AH=clone(H); loop{ AH[i]=AH[i]+AH[i-1]; } where AH=AccumulatedHistogram, H=Histogram. As you can see in the [cumulative distribution function (cdf) example of Histogram Equalization in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization#Small_image). I hope I've made myself clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`calcHist` will return a `Mat` of **`float`** values. Although the type is not well documented, you can easy guess what it is by looking at how [the documentation access its values](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html).

If `image` is a single-channel image, `calcHist` will compute a `histSize x 1` **`float`** matrix, in your example `histogram`.  Note that `histSize` is often called `number of bins`.

To iterate its all values, you can do like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<histSize; i++)
    cout << histogram.at<float>(i, 0));
```

---

Note: For 3-channel image like `RGB`, you can do as follows:

```
vector<float> result;

/// Separate the image in 3 places ( B, G and R )
vector<Mat> bgr_planes;
split( image, bgr_planes );

/// Establish the number of bins
int histSize = 256;

/// Set the ranges ( for B,G,R) )
float range[] = { 0, 256 } ; //0~255 the upper boundary is exclusive
const float * histRange = { range };
bool uniform = true; 
bool accumulate = false;
Mat b_hist, g_hist, r_hist;

/// Compute the histograms:
calcHist( &bgr_planes[0], 1, 0, Mat(), b_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
calcHist( &bgr_planes[1], 1, 0, Mat(), g_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
calcHist( &bgr_planes[2], 1, 0, Mat(), r_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );

/// stored in result
for (int i=0; i<histSize; i++)
    result.push_back(r_hist.at<float>(i, 0));
for (int i=0; i<histSize; i++)
    result.push_back(g_hist.at<float>(i, 0));
for (int i=0; i<histSize; i++)
    result.push_back(b_hist.at<float>(i, 0));
```